# PXRedirectToUrlExcption - controlling window mode (Acumatica 4.2)

Tags: acumatica

I have a situation where I need the ability to show a page from another site in a popup, iframe, current window (which ever I can get to work).

The need for this is at certain point in my process (opportunities), I need to call an external application that manages some specific configuration, then saves that back to the database via WebAPI.

Currently I have a method that builds my url and passes it to a  PXRedirectToUrlException to make the call.   This is being done server side as I need to pull specific data based off the current opportunity to build the correct URL to pass.

What I've found is if the redirect url is in the same base domain as it is on my development server, it works as expected with the WindowMode however if the redirect url is in a different domain, it always opens the new page in a new window/tab.

Debugging the calls I see that when it's on the same page, the call returns a "Redirect0" message however on a different domain it's calling "Redirect4"

Is there a way via the redirect exceptions to do this (open a page in a separate domain either in a popup/iframe/current window) ?

One other option I thought of if not would be to be to have a dummy page, call that page and then via either javascript or standard aspx calls handle the redirect.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a sample before, you can give a try. In this, we create a dummy graph with a DAC for filter and a dummy filter, later we create an aspx with Filter in the form view wch helps to append the URL using some javascript as desired and show the external page in a smart panel.. code is as follows

C#

```
 [Serializable]
    public class UrlFilter : IBqlTable
    {
        #region FilterParam
        public class filterParam : IBqlField { }
        [PXString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Parameter")]
        public string FilterParam { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DummyClass : IBqlTable
    {
    }

    public class UrlGraph : PXGraph<UrlGraph>
    {
        public PXFilter<UrlFilter> Filter;

        public PXFilter<DummyClass> DummyRecord;

        public PXAction<UrlFilter> Action;
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        protected void action()
        {
        }
    }
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function commandResult(ds, context) {
            var paramIdCtrl, smartpanel, param;
            for (var key in ds.px_context.px_all) {
                if (key.indexOf("_edFilterParam") > 0) {
                    paramIdCtrl = ds.px_context.px_all[key];
                }
                if (key.indexOf("_ExternalWebsitePanel") > 0) {
                    smartpanel = ds.px_context.px_all[key];
                }
            }
            if (paramIdCtrl || smartpanel) {
                param = paramIdCtrl.getValue();

                var newUrl = 'http://testsite.com/search.shtml?q=' + param;

                smartpanel.setPageUrl(newUrl);
                smartpanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

FORM AND SMART PANEL

```
           <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" Width="100%" DataMember="Filter" TabIndex="6500">
                <Template>
                    <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule1" runat="server" StartRow="True" ControlSize="M" LabelsWidth="XS" />
                    <px:PXTextEdit ID="edFilterParam" runat="server" DataField="FilterParam" CommitChanges="True">
                        <AutoCallBack Command="Action" Target="ds" />
                    </px:PXTextEdit>
                </Template>
                <AutoSize Container="Parent" Enabled="True" />
            </px:PXFormView>


            <px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" AllowMove="False" AllowResize="False" ID="ExternalWebsitePanel" RenderVisible="True"
                RenderIFrame="True" AutoSize-Enabled="true" SkinID="Frame" LoadOnDemand="True" InnerPageUrl="http://testsite.com/" Position="Original">
            </px:PXSmartPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you Hybridzz.   That will work well.    As a work around for this client what I ended up doing (which i'm not completely happy with) is to create a dummy BLC/DAC like you did but before i redirect to it I set a session key, then in the page load event of the dummy page associated to the dummy BLC see if the viable exists and does a response.redirect.    Your method might work better however.

Comment: Hybridzz:  are you showing this dummy page in a new window or in a popup?   Having trouble with the smartpanel's height.  It comes in at only around 9px high and won't resize.   Just wondering if you have ran into the same issue before

Comment: It was a sample. This will show as a page in acumatica 4.2 as we just added the link in site map.

Comment: For future reference for others.  It's a style issue between browsers.  I has to set AutoSize-Enabled to false then create a stylesheet entry for the smart panel.  Then it sized correctly.